# Mysql row query to codeigniter query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have the following Mysql query. Running as needed.

```
SELECT
    t_doc.*, t_user.IDA, t_data.IDA
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT IDau FROM t_doc ) IDau_list

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                IDd ,IDau
            FROM
                t_doc
            WHERE
                doc_type = 'doc'
            GROUP BY IDau
        )
        doc_images ON doc_images.IDau = IDau_list.IDau

LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                IDd ,IDau
            FROM
                t_auto_doc
            WHERE
                doc_type = 'jpg'
            GROUP BY IDau
        )
        jpg_images ON jpg_images.IDau = IDau_list.IDau

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        t_doc ON t_doc.IDdoc = COALESCE(jpg_images.IDd, doc_images.IDd)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        t_user ON t_user.IDau = t_doc.IDau
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        t_data ON t_user.IDA = t_data.IDA
```

But, What I must bring this query to codeigniter Model, in which I have to adapt the query, as example like this...

```
 $this->db->select('u.IDau, a.*');
 $this->db->from('t_user u'); 
 $this->db->join('t_doc d', 'd.IDau=u.IDau', 'left');
 And ...More.....Here......
```

But, I got it difficult. Is some one out there might change it Please..
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I am not sure, but i think that query builder class can't handle such complicated query... but you always can use: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Comment: The question is, How do i change the above long MYSQL QUERY to CODEIGNITER Query Style as you see below? Or in short How do I bring the above Long MYSQL QUERY to CODEIGNTER?

Comment: I think you are looking the way to nest selects with active record. If so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957855/convert-the-nesting-mysql-query-into-codeigniter-style

Comment: @MR.Internet, why you can't  use: $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE'); ?

Comment: I agree with @nevermind. In my experience if i have a query as complicated as that i will `$this->db->query('mysql query')`. Because sometimes this is more readable for me.

Comment: Let me work on your suggestion..will let you know if goes ok or not...

Comment: if you are using CI-3 did you try query grouping http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Comment: me agree with @nevermind For any complex queries, I typically build the query manually and use $this->db->query() with parameter binding. If it gets really complex, I'll leave some placeholders in the query, like it was a view template, almost, and then do string replacement with the correct queries until I have what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NEVERMIND Suggest I have accomplish the task using...

```
$query = $this->db->query("My QUERY WITH A BIT OF CHANGE");
```

Yes, I should make some change to get the exact Data as i needed.

Thanks for all of your comments and ideas.